# Long held TCP connection gets destroyed randomly from conntrack

Tags: java, sockets, kubernetes, tcp

It all started with Connection reset error on our Java app running on Kubernetes connected to external Oracle DB, the original issue described at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73051447/java-app-on-kubernetes-still-uses-broken-connection-after-connection-reset-by-pe)
Basically we have a Java app which when started and user logs in, it creates long living connection to Oracle DB which stays active for a lifetime of an app (or a kubernetes POD in this case). Issue is that after some time, it can be 30 minutes, it can be even 2 days, there is an error in logs

```
[pool-16-thread-1] WARN  c.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection - HikariPool-2 - Connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@51f5db67 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(17002)
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset by peer
```

which results in a lot of SQL errors afterwards, because said active connection still tries to use the broken connection. As it turns out, it looks like hibernate session gets created but never cleaned up as I believe it should always create a new session when interacting with DB. I have pointed this out to our developers but no idea when this will get fixed.
We are currently trying to migrate the app to kubernetes and the main issue for me is why this Connection reset happens on kubernetes? This does not happen on a plain virtual machine for example, although the java app is same. The app is scaled to 2 PODs and the issue sometimes happens only for one POD, sometimes after 5-10 minutes on the second POD as well so this kind of excludes network glitch as it should then happen on both PODs at the same time I would guess. Also it seems like this happens mostly when there is some load on traffic, eg. clients requesting lots of data from DB
So I started to gather tcpdump from kubernetes POD and node and also conntrack event log from node and found that the TCP connection gets destroyed randomly, please bear with me:

`10.244.1.143` is POD IP,
`10.203.8.166` is NODE IP,
`10.203.0.16`  is Oracle DB

This is the conntrack event log:

```
[17:31:49.398663]       [NEW] tcp      6 120 SYN_SENT src=10.244.1.143 dst=10.203.0.16 sport=59048 dport=1521 [UNREPLIED] src=10.203.0.16 dst=10.203.8.166 sport=1521 dport=42662
[17:31:49.398757]    [UPDATE] tcp      6 60 SYN_RECV src=10.244.1.143 dst=10.203.0.16 sport=59048 dport=1521 src=10.203.0.16 dst=10.203.8.166 sport=1521 dport=42662
[17:31:49.398779]    [UPDATE] tcp      6 432000 ESTABLISHED src=10.244.1.143 dst=10.203.0.16 sport=59048 dport=1521 src=10.203.0.16 dst=10.203.8.166 sport=1521 dport=42662 [ASSURED]
```

TCPDUMP from POD

```
62  17:31:49.396366 10.244.1.143    59048   10.203.0.16 1521    TNS 286 64  Request, Connect (1)
63  17:31:49.396522 10.203.0.16 1521    10.244.1.143    59048   TCP 66  62  1521 → 59048 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=221 Win=45056 Len=0 TSval=2508525336 TSecr=1587061054
64  17:31:49.407027 10.203.0.16 1521    10.244.1.143    59048   TNS 74  62  Response, Resend (11)
65  17:31:49.407041 10.244.1.143    59048   10.203.0.16 1521    TCP 66  64  59048 → 1521 [ACK] Seq=221 Ack=9 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1587061065 TSecr=2508525346
66  17:31:49.407566 10.244.1.143    59048   10.203.0.16 1521    TNS 286 64  Request, Connect (1)
67  17:31:49.407791 10.203.0.16 1521    10.244.1.143    59048   TNS 98  62  Response, Accept (2)
```

TCPDUMP from Node

```
15880   17:31:49.396400 10.203.8.166    42662   10.203.0.16 1521    TNS 286 63  Request, Connect (1)
15881   17:31:49.396497 10.203.0.16 1521    10.203.8.166    42662   TCP 66  63  1521 → 42662 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=221 Win=45056 Len=0 TSval=2508525336 TSecr=1587061054
15882   17:31:49.406999 10.203.0.16 1521    10.203.8.166    42662   TNS 74  63  Response, Resend (11)
15883   17:31:49.407076 10.203.8.166    42662   10.203.0.16 1521    TCP 66  63  42662 → 1521 [ACK] Seq=221 Ack=9 Win=64256 Len=0 TSval=1587061065 TSecr=2508525346
15884   17:31:49.407601 10.203.8.166    42662   10.203.0.16 1521    TNS 286 63  Request, Connect (1)
15885   17:31:49.407767 10.203.0.16 1521    10.203.8.166    42662   TNS 98  63  Response, Accept (2)
```

so we can see that the connection is established and everything is fine. It keeps working for some time (in this case it was something like 18hours when clients started to send more requests in the next day)

From TCPDUMP some of the last packets sent were at 12:21:20 before connection reset happened
FROM POD

```
1095701 12:21:20.201049 10.203.0.16 1521    10.244.1.143    59048   TCP 1514    62  [TCP Spurious Retransmission] 1521 → 59048 [ACK] Seq=1235168 Ack=9324 Win=126976 Len=1448 TSval=2576296140 TSecr=1654831858
1095702 12:21:20.201125 10.244.1.143    59048   10.203.0.16 1521    TCP 78  64  [TCP Dup ACK 1095694#3] 59048 → 1521 [ACK] Seq=9324 Ack=1245969 Win=1552128 Len=0 TSval=1654831859 TSecr=2576296140 SLE=1235168 SRE=1236616
1095703 12:21:20.201059 10.203.0.16 1521    10.244.1.143    59048   TCP 1514    62  [TCP Spurious Retransmission] 1521 → 59048 [ACK] Seq=1236616 Ack=9324 Win=126976 Len=1448 TSval=2576296140 TSecr=1654831858
1095704 12:21:20.201137 10.244.1.143    59048   10.203.0.16 1521    TCP 78  64  [TCP Dup ACK 1095694#4] 59048 → 1521 [ACK] Seq=9324 Ack=1245969 Win=1552128 Len=0 TSval=1654831859 TSecr=2576296140 SLE=1236616 SRE=1238064
1095705 12:21:20.201067 10.203.0.16 1521    10.244.1.143    59048   TCP 1514    62  [TCP Spurious Retransmission] 1521 → 59048 [ACK] Seq=1238064 Ack=9324 Win=126976 Len=1448 TSval=2576296140 TSecr=1654831858
1095706 12:21:20.201142 10.244.1.143    59048   10.203.0.16 1521    TCP 78  64  [TCP Dup ACK 1095694#5] 59048 → 1521 [ACK] Seq=9324 Ack=1245969 Win=1552128 Len=0 TSval=1654831859 TSecr=2576296140 SLE=1238064 SRE=1239512
```

FROM NODE

```
1116282 12:21:20.201173 10.203.8.166    42662   10.203.0.16 1521    TCP 78  63  [TCP Window Update] 42662 → 1521 [ACK] Seq=9324 Ack=1245969 Win=1552128 Len=0 TSval=1654831859 TSecr=2576296140 SLE=1230824 SRE=1232272
1116283 12:21:20.201225 10.203.8.166    42662   10.203.0.16 1521    TCP 78  63  [TCP Dup ACK 1116275#1] 42662 → 1521 [ACK] Seq=9324 Ack=1245969 Win=1552128 Len=0 TSval=1654831859 TSecr=2576296140 SLE=1232272 SRE=1233720
1116284 12:21:20.201275 10.203.8.166    42662   10.203.0.16 1521    TCP 78  63  [TCP Dup ACK 1116275#2] 42662 → 1521 [ACK] Seq=9324 Ack=1245969 Win=1552128 Len=0 TSval=1654831859 TSecr=2576296140 SLE=1233720 SRE=1235168
1116285 12:21:20.201313 10.203.8.166    42662   10.203.0.16 1521    TCP 78  63  [TCP Dup ACK 1116275#3] 42662 → 1521 [ACK] Seq=9324 Ack=1245969 Win=1552128 Len=0 TSval=1654831859 TSecr=2576296140 SLE=1235168 SRE=1236616
1116286 12:21:20.201350 10.203.8.166    42662   10.203.0.16 1521    TCP 78  63  [TCP Dup ACK 1116275#4] 42662 → 1521 [ACK] Seq=9324 Ack=1245969 Win=1552128 Len=0 TSval=1654831859 TSecr=2576296140 SLE=1236616 SRE=1238064
1116287 12:21:20.201361 10.203.8.166    42662   10.203.0.16 1521    TCP 78  63  [TCP Dup ACK 1116275#5] 42662 → 1521 [ACK] Seq=9324 Ack=1245969 Win=1552128 Len=0 TSval=1654831859 TSecr=2576296140 SLE=1238064 SRE=1239512
```

But then in conntrack event log next entry pops up saying

```
[12:27:26.363550]       [DESTROY] tcp      6 src=10.244.1.143 dst=10.203.0.16 sport=59048 dport=1521 src=10.203.0.16 dst=10.203.8.166 sport=1521 dport=42662 [ASSURED]
```

No idea why it got destroyed, but from TCPDUMP there is nothing after 12:21:20 till 12:58:07 when POD tries to use the same connection  and gets RST packet, which closes the connection

```
1146526 12:58:07.841757 10.244.1.143    59048   10.203.0.16 1521    TNS 241 64  Request, Data (6), Piggy back function follow
1146527 12:58:07.842107 10.203.0.16 1521    10.244.1.143    59048   TCP 54  62  1521 → 59048 [RST] Seq=1245969 Win=0 Len=0
```

but on TCPDUMP from NODE this same request goes already on different port, 14242 in this case

```
1167107 12:58:07.841914 10.203.8.166    14242   10.203.0.16 1521    TNS 241 63  Request, Data (6), Piggy back function follow
1167109 12:58:07.842051 10.203.0.16 1521    10.203.8.166    14242   TCP 60  63  1521 → 14242 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0
```

Also when this happens, there are new entries in conntrack event log saying that new connection was created on port 14242 and immediately destroyed, I suppose because of RST

```
[12:58:07.842067]           [NEW] tcp      6 300 ESTABLISHED src=10.244.1.143 dst=10.203.0.16 sport=59048 dport=1521 [UNREPLIED] src=10.203.0.16 dst=10.203.8.166 sport=1521 dport=14242
[12:58:07.842138]       [DESTROY] tcp      6 src=10.244.1.143 dst=10.203.0.16 sport=59048 dport=1521 [UNREPLIED] src=10.203.0.16 dst=10.203.8.166 sport=1521 dport=14242
```

I am pretty sure Oracle sends the RST and closes the connection, because it comes from different SRC IP, but what exactly happened at 12:27:26 and why did the connection get destroyed?
I would really appreciate any help on debugging this, might not be related to kubernetes at all.
I am using this [canal](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/manifests/canal.yaml) as my CNI if that helps

Just to add, after restarting POD everything works for some time again till the next connection reset

Comment: Is this really a *programming* question?  It sounds more like a *networking* or *systems administration* problem.  Try https://serverfault.com

Comment: start with [Using JDBC with Firewalls](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxtblsh.htm#JJDBC28984)

Comment: @StephenC I have already [tried](https://serverfault.com/questions/1107756/debugging-kubernetes-connection-reset-by-peer-to-external-oracle-db) but unfortunately with no luck. this place seems more active and I have seen similar questions being answered here so I decided to try